# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using Password NO

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.0, ssh, query-performance

I have enabled SQL SLOW LOG Queries in *my.cnf* file but i need to restart mysql and when i try to run this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

for restarting it throws this error.

```
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld already running.
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/debian.cnf' is ignored
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

[Image] :

[image]

Comment: Firstly you must check your error log to see why MySQL server failed to stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to incorrect permissions on **/etc/mysql/debian.cnf** file.

Do a long-listing of that file first to check current permissions:

```
sudo ls -l /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

If group or other fields has write permission enabled, run:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

and then restart mysql:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```